# in body click div hide, when i click on div also it hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show a div on link click and hide if click outside the link or div.

```
<a href="#" class='login' id="login">login </a>
<div class="login-panel"> 
    <input type="text" id="LoginForm_username" name="LoginForm[username]" class="field" value="username">
    <input type="password" id="LoginForm_password" name="LoginForm[password]" class="field" value="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login"  class="loginBtn">
</div>
```

initially div is hidden. and script is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").click(function () {
        $("div.login-panel").toggle();
    });

    $("body").click(function(e){
        if(e.target.className == "login" || e.target.className == "login-panel") { 
            //alert("do't hide");  
        }
        else {
            $(".login-panel").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

when I click on link div shows and overlaps some other elements, and when I click outside the body it dies.
But the problem is when I click on input box to enter username login-panel div get hides.
why div hide?
any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/F4p2x/15/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").click(function(e) {
        $(".login-panel").toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is('.login-panel, .login-panel *')) {
            $(".login-panel").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/VWENB/1/

```
$("#login").click(function(e) {
    $("div.login-panel").toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$("body").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.className == "field") {
        //alert("do't hide");  
    } else {
        $(".login-panel").hide();

    }
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are clicking on a sub-element, your condition (e.target.className) is not applied to your parent element (`<div class="login-panel">`). But you can use the `closest` function of jQuery (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)) in order to test if you are in your parent element :

```
if(e.target.className == "login" ||  $(e.target).closest(".login-panel").length === 1) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> PROBLEM is when i click on input box to enter username login-panel div
>   get hides. why div hide?

Because, you clicked the body too, when clicking in the div. Then both events are triggered. Check out [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) which you may use in the else part of body.onclick.

Comment: if both event are triggered e.target.className == "login-panel" should be true.correct if i am wrong

Comment: Hm, yes. This sounds reasonable. Have you tried to stop propagation?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#login").click(function () {
        $("div.login-panel").toggle();
    });
    $("body").click(function (e) {
        if (e.target.nodeName != "INPUT" && e.target.className!= "login" && e.target.className!= "login-panel") {
            $(".login-panel").hide();
        }
    });
});​
```

You were using the wrong selector in your `if` to check if a click on the body wasn't targeting a input element.

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4bgsX/3/)

Answer (score 0):

That because your input lies inside `#login` div, so if you click inside this div it will hide. So you can use jquery [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)  selector to specify those excluded elements

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#login,:not('#LoginForm_username'),:not('#LoginForm_password')").click(function () {
            $("div.login-panel").toggle();
        });
        $("body").click(function (e) {
            if (e.target.className == "login" || e.target.className == "login-panel") {
                //alert("do't hide");  
            } else {
                $(".login-panel").hide();

            }
        });
    });​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZggTt/)

Answer (score 0):

As the other saying clicking input cause event triggering in the body so you should check if the sender is child of the login I think below code do the trick;

```
$("body").click(function (e) {

        var $sender = $(e.target);
        if ($sender.closest(".login-panel").length) {
            return ;
        } 
            $(".login-panel").hide();
    });
```

Edit : update the condition with closest as it is correct function.

Begins with the current element, Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector. The returned jQuery object contains zero or one element for each element in the original set.

Answer (score 0):

Just find mouse when the click event occur,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 find_mouse = false;

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.login-panel').hover(function(){ 
        find_mouse=true;  // if mouse on login-panel
    }, function(){ 
        find_mouse=false; // not on login panel
    });

    $("body").click(function(){ 
        if(! find_mouse) // if not on login panel
        $('.login-panel').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Here the question not for touch devices.!@jigneshkheni